# Why does not gitlab ci execute the rule?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

```
release-gate:
stage: release-gate
script:
  - RCM_APPROVAL=$(cat result.json)
  - echo $RCM_APPROVAL
rules:
 - if: '$RCM_APPROVAL == "0"'
   when: manual
 - when: always
```

Folks, even though `echo $RCM_APPROVAL' returns the result as expected, the if condition under rules: does not work. Could you please let me know If I am missing anything here?

Comment: Why do you have `when: manual`?

Comment: I need this job to be triggered manually only when RCM_APPROVAL is  "0"'

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, what are you trying to execute when RCM_APPROVAL is "0"?

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this. When RCM_APPROVAL is 0, I need the job to be triggered manually by clicking the play button on the job in the pipeline. If it is 1, I need the job tobe triggered automatically and completed.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here the. With this yaml you're saying that the job `release-gate` will run if your conditions are met, but the value of `RCM_APPROVAL` is computed inside the job. This means that you need to run the job before being able to evaluate that condition, which is clearly not the behavior you need.

Comment: Thanks. You make sense. I misunderstood the syntax. Still figuring out a way to pass the variable between jobs; so that I can store a value to on the previous job and used in the second job (release-gate) to determine if the job has to be triggered automatically or not.

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question then, I don't think this one will get enough attention to help you out. I'll see if I can recover something I did a long time ago to deal with a similar situation, but I can't make promises on this.